# How do I build a wrapper (or launcher and receiver upon completion) for an external app in Android?

Tags: android

I'm working with a partner who has an app (App A) that wishes to call my app (App B). Once called App A will then wait for App B to finish what it's doing and collect some data.

In the exact scenario I'm working in, App A collects user info (name, phone) and then needs to pass it to App B. App B will do some stuff with that info and when finished, needs to notify App A that it succeeded (or didn't succeed) to perform operations for user name_phone.

What do our apps need to know about each other for this to work?

I'm looking at `startActivityForResult` but I'm getting the impression that's something one would use within ones own application and not something App A can use to launch App B.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivityForResult()` works fine between applications. You should take a look at Barcode Scanner by [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) to see how they use `startActivityForResult()` for this very purpose.

App B will need to have an `Activity` with an `<intent-filter>` that will be stable, such as one using a custom action string. App B will also need to document what the `Intent` should look like (e.g., required action, required `Uri` if any, extras), and what will be returned via `onActivityResult()`.

The author of App B could create a JAR file that provides a cleaner API for App A to use. ZXing did that with Barcode Scanner.

Comment: thanks!  I started to poke around the ZXing source, but BOY is there a lot of it!  I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by a stable intent-filter. The initial Activity (Main) is the one that is my Launcher activity in App B.  When you say App B will need to "document" the extras, URI etc, I'm not clear on what you mean by that either.  But I guess I'll just examine startActivityForResult examples and see if I can deduce what you mean from those.

Comment: @Dr. Dredel: "I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by a stable intent-filter." -- meaning something that won't change just because you decide to rename your activity class or refactor your code or something. "When you say App B will need to 'document' the extras, URI etc, I'm not clear on what you mean by that either." -- how do you expect the author of App A to know what to do to use App B? Mind meld? A million monkeys on a million copies of Emacs trying out random code to see if it works? Personally, I would expect documentation. Or, at least, for the monkeys to use a better editor. :-)

Comment: @Dr. Dredel: For example, here is the documentation for integrating with ZXing: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent  As docs go, it's nothing spectacular, but it's something.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean... I wasn't thinking in terms of documentation because this is a very simple app being written by two blokes, so, my intention is to write him an email that says "start the app by calling ...." I suppose that qualifies as "documentation" :)  It's not meant for public consumption, and will never be re-used. But I like the imagery of the monkeys on emacs.

Comment: @Dr. Dredel: Ah, I see. Yeah, the docs can be scrawled on the back of a napkin, or delivered verbally, or in the form of a dancing-gorilla-gram. But, somehow, you will need some form of inter-bloke communication (IBC) so App A's bloke knows what to code to and App B's bloke knows what it is obligated to support. I tend to think of these things as being more formal -- my apologies.